# Preventing overflow:hidden from cropping the image

Tags: css, sass, overflow

I'm working on a carousel right now, modeled after Facebook's F8 photo carousel at the bottom of [their page](https://www.fbf8.com/).

My carousel structure is the same basically:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```

For the SCSS I have

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 450px;
  overflow: hidden;
  div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 1400px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 1400px 450px;
    background: url('...');
    height: 100%;
  }
  &:nth-child(2) { left: 1400px; }
}
```

The nested child divs inside the container are both larger than the screen width and I want to scroll them horizontally. However, I've set overflow:hidden on the container to constrain the carousel to the width of the page so when it scrolls past the end of my screen, the rest of the div is cropped.

To scroll the carousel horizontally, I set an interval and use transform: translateX() to shift it by a couple pixels every few ms.

How can I get it to not crop the image but also not allow the user to scroll sideways past the screen dimensions?

Comment: Please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We can't possibly fix your CSS without seeing it.

Comment: @ObsidianAge Hey sorry about that, I just updated my question with the styles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jk dumb mistake, I was translating the container element.

I fixed it by making the container element the entire width of the two images, and then enclosing that in another container element which had overflow: hidden and width: 100%.